# How to efficiently generate random tests in Haskell Test.QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, testing, random, quickcheck

I'd like to generate some sample tests using Haskell Test.QuickCheck

The goal is to generate data of (Int, [Int]) with the following conditions where the tuple is (x, xs):

1. x > 0
2. x not in xs
3. all xs >0

Scratching my head and stumbling through the manual https://github.com/stackbuilders/quickcheck-manual after some time I can produce random lists meeting these requirements:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
mygen = arbitrary::Gen (Int, [Int]))
sample (mygen `suchThat` ( \(x, xs)->( (x `notElem` xs) && (x > 0) && (all (>0) xs)&& (xs/=[]))))
```

Running the last line in the GHCI outputs something like:

```
(40,[19,35,27,29,45,1,17,28])
(20,[3,9,11,12,15,8])
(43,[76,102,106,71,24,2,29,101,59,48])
(99,[5,87,136,131,22,22,133])
(77,[11,14,55,47,78,15,14])
...
```

Questions:

1. How can this be done more efficiently since - I'm guessing- the function mygen creates a large sample set then filters out based on the `suchThat` criteria
2. How can I indicate the list xs should be of a certain size. For example if I add `&& length xs > 50` the program runs for a very long time.
3. Guarantee that each element of xs is unique. I.e. avoid records like (99,[22,22])

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, assuming the probability that a generated number is positive is 1/2, then the probability of getting a list of 50 positive numbers is (1/2)^50, or 1 in 1,125,899,906,842,624.  So yeah, that's not gonna happen.

Instead of generating lists and filtering them, I would suggest building lists you need by transforming generators.

```
mygen :: Gen (Int, [Int])
mygen = do 
    x <- getPositive <$> arbitrary
    xs <- delete x <$> replicateM 50 (getPositive <$> arbitrary)
    return (x, xs)
```

Now you are guaranteed to get a list matching your criteria immediately.

As for uniqueness, see [`Data.List.nub`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub).  You might also consider using a [`Data.Set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.1/docs/Data-Set.html), since it seems you are using it that way.

Comment: `abs <$> arbitrary` can still yield `0`. You can use `positive = getPositive <$> arbitrary` to generate only positive numbers.

Comment: The generator for `xs` creates a list with at most 50 elements, not at least 50. For at least 50 elements, you could do something like `n <- getNonNegative <$> arbitrary; xs <- replicateM (n+50) (arbitrary \`suchThat\` (/= x))`.

Comment: Thanks! Insightful.   Is there a way to guarantee xs contains 50 elements?  If I do something like nub.delete... `mygen = do 
    x <- getPositive <$> arbitrary
    xs <- nub.delete x <$> replicateM 50 (getPositive <$> arbitrary)
    return (x, xs)`  returns fairly small lists `(1,[1,2,3])
(2,[2,1,3])
(1,[4,1,3,2])
(4,[3,2,1,6,5,4])
(7,[1,2,8,6,5,7,4,3])`  because many of the elements are thrown out...

Comment: @brander, hm, you might be able to use a smaller-scoped `suchThat` for that.  Say ``(getPositive <$> arbitrary) `suchThat` (`notElem` alreadyGenerated)`` -- recursively with `alreadyGenerated` as the accumulator.